# Replace space with dash before save using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to save a name to the database and a single word (firstname) works fine but when the user enter both firstname and lastname I want Rails to save it to the database as firstname-lastname instead of firstname lastname (space between).

I know I perhaps should use a before create filter but I am not sure how this need to look like. I want the validation to work to, i.e. no two people should be able to use the same name.

I am using Rails 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just have first_name and last_name columns in the db, and create your own validation rule to make sure the combination is unique (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods). You should also create a unique index over those two columns in your db.

Answer (score 64):

You can use ActiveSupport's inflector method `parameterize` on the string.

```
name = 'john smith'     # => john smith
name.parameterize       # => john-smith
```

Further, parameterize takes an option to use for the word-break, so you can replace the dash with an underscore like this:

```
name.parameterize("_")  # => john_smith
```

An advantage of using parameterize is that it normalizes the characters to the latin, so...

```
name = "jöhanne såltveç"
name.parameterize       # => johanne-saltvec
```

**EDIT**: As of [Rails 5.0.0.1](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.0.0.1/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize) the separator needs to be passed as an option. Therefore: `name.parameterize(separator: '_')`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! A helper from rails! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to us regexp and replace all existing spaces with. You'd put something along the lines of:

```
self.firstname.gsub(/\s+/, '-')
```

in your model.

Note: I'm not sure if ruby accepts `\s` as "any whitespace character" And I think the * should make sure that if someone enters a name with two neighbour spaces(or more) it won't convert each space into a separate dash, but only into one.

Comment: @Gearóid Oh, you are right! I meant to type `+` not `*`! Sorry about that. =P

Answer (score 0):

Other answer is correct,

But, if you want to preserve case while parameterizing

```
name = "Donald Duck"
name.parameterize(preserve_case: true)   # => Donald-Duck
```